# Select record based on multi-row criteria

Tags: sql-server

So here's the deal. I have a table with the following sample data.

**Edit**: This table has a many-to-one relationship with the `"PEOPLE"` table.

Table_A

```
ID   |CODE   |TYPE   | BAL
-----|-------|-------|------
1    |AR     |FO     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
1    |RT     |CM     |335.00
-----|-------|-------|------
2    |AR     |CU     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
3    |RT     |CM     |167.00
-----|-------|-------|------
4    |AR     |CU     |500.00
-----|-------|-------|------
4    |RT     |CM     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
5    |RT     |CM     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
6    |AR     |FO     |200.00
-----|-------|-------|------
7    |AR     |CU     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
7    |RT     |CM     |0.00
```

I need to select all records in which if they only have one row then `CODE IN ('AR', 'RT') AND BAL <= 0`, but if they have two rows then I only need the ones that both `BAL` columns are `<= 0`.

**Example**:

---

The query should return:

**Edit**: Later I will add the `DISTINCT` to the query, but for now I'm just curious on how to get the records.

```
ID   |CODE   |TYPE   | BAL
-----|-------|-------|------
2    |AR     |CU     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
5    |RT     |CM     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
7    |AR     |CU     |0.00
-----|-------|-------|------
7    |RT     |CM     |0.00
```

So pretty much I need to evaluate whether or not the `BAL <= 0` and if they have two rows than both rows should have `BAL <= 0`.

I've tried different `WHERE` clauses with no luck. Let me know if you all need more information and I can add it here.

Comment: @NelsonCasanova The table is a one to many relationship with the table that contains the `ID`s. So kind of like banking one person can have multiple accounts.

Comment: What's the primary key of `Table_A`? Can there be more than two rows with a given `people` `ID`? If so, should they only be displayed if *all* rows have `bal <= 0`, or if at least two rows have `bal <= 0`? if not all rows need to have `bal <= 0`, should all rows be displayed, or only those with `bal <= 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table_A]
WHERE [ID] IN
(
    SELECT [ID]
    FROM [Table_A]
    GROUP BY [ID]
    HAVING (
            COUNT(*)=1 AND 
            MAX(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('AR', 'RT') 
                AND BAL <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1
            ) 
            OR 
            (
            COUNT(*)>1 AND MAX(BAL)<=0
            )
)
```

Comment: Nice! I would never thought to do it this way, but that's what I like about programming. There are always 100 different ways of solving the same problem.